# Any faster way to concatenate arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I have a function that does the following:

- Gets an array and then does arbitrary operations with slices of the array, generating new arrays
- Concatenates all the new arrays into a single array and returns it.

A very straightforward way i started was with the following code using np.concatenate:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

arr = np.ones(10000)

@njit(fastmath=True)
def EQ1(a):
    
    eq1 = 2*a[1:-1]
    eq2 = 4*a[0:2]
    
    sys = (eq1,eq2)
    
    sys = np.concatenate(sys)
    
    return sys
```

Then i decided to look for faster answers, and oddly, doing a numba jitted function appending each individual element to a pre-allocated array is significantly faster:

```
@njit(fastmath=True)
def EQ2(a):
    
    sys = np.empty_like(a)
    l = 0
    for i in range(1,len(a)-1):
        eq1 = 2*a[i]
        sys[l] = eq1
        l+=1
   
    for i in range(2):
        eq2 = 4*a[i]
        sys[l] = eq2
        l+=1
    
    return sys

%timeit EQ1(arr) 6.31 µs ± 9.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit EQ2(arr) 3.48 µs ± 2.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But the second approach starts occupying a lot of space as the number of eqs grows. So i'm wondering there are any faster alternatives. I already experimented with append(), extend() but the for loop jitted is still faster. Thanks

Comment: I wonder why the second approach needs more space than the first. Do you keep the original array `a` and the returned array from the functions together?

Comment: By space i meant that the code starts getting too big

Comment: Since AFAIK Numpa does not support things like lazy arrays evaluation (nor stack allocations as a mainstream feature), loops are the way to go. Higher performance is often reached using bigger code (a more explicit one or simply one with many special cases supported). There is no free lunch. Note however that the variable `l`, `eq1` and `eq2` are not really needed here. In the end, the code is just a bit bigger without them.

Comment: It isn't odd that the second one is faster, you should *expect* numba to be able to effectively optimize the second one, but not the first one, which just calls out to numpy functions. Doing it the numpy way slows you down because you need to create a bunch of intermediate arrays. Preallocation is usually faster, you effectively only do one pass over the data instead of several redundant ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not *exactly* asking about catenation speed.
Rather, to accomplish a task, you are asking
"how many memory operations do I need?"
With the goal of being lazy,
of doing as little as possible.

We're doing essentially no computation here;
it is entirely an exercise focused on
moving chunks of memory around.

## EQ1

These operations have negligible cost and
won't be considered further:

```
    eq2 = 4 * a[0:2]
    sys = (eq1, eq2)
```

We will take "writing a bunch of ones",
`arr = np.ones(10_000)`, as "one memory operation",
an array's worth of writes across the bus to DRAM.
It is my belief that it happens in a sensible way,
with each cache line being written just once.
So that is our timing unit.

```
    eq1 = 2 * a[1:-1]
```

Here we read one unit, which thanks to caching
seems to have zero cost in a run-many-times
benching context.
We trivially double each item,
and send that to a temp var
at a cost of one unit.

```
    sys = np.concatenate(sys)
```

Now `concatenate` reads one (cached) unit
at zero cost,
and incurs the expense of an additional
unit of writing to newly allocated storage.

Total: two units.

## EQ2

The `range(2)` loop has negligible cost
and won't be considered further.
Similarly the `.empty_like()`.

```
    for i in range(1, len(a) - 1):
        eq1 = 2 * a[i]
        sys[l] = eq1
        l += 1
```

Reading `a` from cache we get for free, pretty much.
Storing double that to `sys` costs us one unit.
Multiplying by two is not a bottleneck
in this pipeline, relative to memory
operations.
Buffering the result in a register
for a moment, rather than in DRAM
for a while, is a big win.

---

So the temp vars of EQ1 cost two units of memory operations,
while EQ2 cost us just one unit.

Moral of the story: "big" temp vars are costly,
as they aren't cache friendly.